# 'ServiceStack.MiniProfiler.IHtmlString' does not contain a definition for 'AsRaw'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, servicestack

I have installed servicestack MVC in a MVC4 app through nuget and trying to enable the mini profiler.

I have done as per the instructions the following in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object src, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Request.IsLocal)
            ServiceStack.MiniProfiler.Profiler.Start();
    }

protected void Application_EndRequest(object src, EventArgs e)
    {
        ServiceStack.MiniProfiler.Profiler.Stop();
    }
```

And I placed the @ServiceStack.MiniProfiler.Profiler.RenderIncludes().AsRaw() in the layout page. However, this method does not exist in this reference. I can only see "ToHtmlString()" & "ToString()" in "@ServiceStack.MiniProfiler.Profiler.RenderIncludes()" which renders the html escaped. Has the "AsRaw()" method been removed in MVC4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`T.AsRaw()` is an extension method in [ServiceStack.Html.HtmlExtensions.AsRaw](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/Html/HtmlExtensions.cs) so you basically need to include the **ServiceStack.Html** namespace.